# Why does os.cpu_count() returns the count of CPU of a node rather than a pod or container?

Tags: python, count, cpu

In python Jupter Notebook on Kubeflow, when I call the os.cpu_count(), it returns the count of the whole node, rather than that of my pod or container. This is somewhat confusing. I want to create multiprocessing tasks according to CPU count, but this function causes me mistake the CPU count of my pod. In fact, the CPU count of node is much greater than that of my pod. So I have to look up the configuration file of kubeflow pod to get the real number of CPU. It seems that there is not a function to tell the CPU count of pod in Python IDE. Right?

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

p=mp.Pool(processes=os.cpu_count())
```

If there is function, just like os.cpu_count(), that could tell me the real CPU count of my pod, that would be great.

Comment: Depends on how the CPU limit set. If an affinity is set `cpu_count()` will return the correct value. It there is a CPU usage limit, the value is also correct, the CPUs are available, but they are limited in utilization. `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu.max` will show the limitations.